# Reboot the remote system is not working?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried the below code, it was not reboot my remote pc's.

```
for line in readips.readlines():
    line = line.strip()
    print("The ip address is : ") + str(line)
    rebootsys = "ssh root@"+str(line) + " reboot"
    print("The reboot system ip is:") + str(rebootsys)
    if(os.system(rebootsys %locals())==0):
        print("Done")
    else:
        print("Not able to reboot")
```

Successfully print the IP when print statement is executing. I was run step by step by using wing IDE. When system starts to execute if condition `if(os.system(rebootsys %locals())==0` it is simply idle, it will not move to next step, if it reboot then it has to move `print("Done")` else it has to move else part, but simply waiting the if condition itself. What to do
 I need to reboot multiple ubuntu system from my ubuntu system through python script.

Comment: have you tried typing that command? is it set up to authenticate with a certificate so that you don't have to enter a password?

Comment: ya i already create a password less login by using ssh-keygen -t dsa and also i tried it manually from command like ssh root@192.168.1.100 reboot. it was rebooted. But by executing it through script, it will not work. Note: i need to reboot multiple system. the for loop of my code should execute n time. if it hangs on "if(os.system(rebootsys %locals()) == 0): line, i will not reboot remaining system also. Help me

Comment: I don't think you need the `% locals()` in there.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to switch to [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module and catch output from the command launched and then decide what to do next with launched process. Let's say using `system()` is not considered as good practice these days for many reasons, from elegance to security.

Good example what can you really do with this module are in sections [17.1.4.3. Replacing os.system()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system) and [17.1.4.5. Replacing os.popen(), os.popen2(), os.popen3()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-popen-os-popen2-os-popen3). Trust me, using that is worth investment of couple lines of more code :-)